# Upgrading Minimal Racket and DrRacket

Tags: racket, raco

I'm on Mac OS X Sierra and I've been using homebrew to get hold of minimal racket and then adding the things I want on top via raco.  One of those things being drracket.

However after upgrading from 6.10 to 6.11 things have gone a bit awry.   When I did the brew upgrade the operation in brew went smoothly and not produce any errors.  However drracket then failed to launch with the following:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/minimal-racket/6.10/lib/racket/Racket.framework/Versions/6.11_3m/Racket
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/bin//DrRacket.app/Contents/MacOS/DrRacket
>     Reason: image not found
>   [1]    64747 abort      drracket

Which would seem to suggest it's unhappy about a reference from 6.10 to 6.11.  In googling I saw raco had a migrate option so I tried:

```
raco pkg migrate 6.10
```

Which produces:

> raco pkg migrate 6.10
>   No packages from "6.10" to install

So I thought I'd do the uninstall re-install dance:

> --- ~ » raco pkg remove drracket
>   raco pkg remove: cannot remove packages that are dependencies of other packages
>     dependencies:
>      drracket (required by: (racket-doc))
>
> --- ~ » raco pkg remove racket-doc                                     raco pkg remove: cannot remove packages that are dependencies of
>   other packages   dependencies:    racket-doc (required by:
>   (slideshow-doc future-visualizer r6rs-doc pict-doc draw-doc plot-doc
>   beautiful-racket data-doc br-parser-tools-doc rackunit-doc srfi-doc
>   typed-racket-doc net-doc gui-doc compatibility-doc
>   beautiful-racket-lib xrepl-doc mzscheme-doc r5rs-doc quickcheck
>   distributed-places-doc reprovide-lang drracket string-constants-doc
>   math-doc parser-tools-doc profile-doc macro-debugger brag db-doc sugar
>   planet-doc syntax-color-doc scribble-doc readline-doc web-server-doc
>   trace drracket-tool-doc doc-coverage errortrace-doc net-cookies-doc
>   beautiful-racket-demo))
>   --- ~ »

So now I'm not sure how to proceed.  I'm pretty sure I should be doing something different to upgrade but I'm not clear what.

Comment: IIUC, the homebrew formula is not “official”, so I don’t think it’s officially supported. Generally, the Racket installers for macOS install “in-place”, so separate installations are essentially sandboxed (hence the reason for `raco pkg migrate`). I don’t know exactly what the error in your question indicates, but you might try running `raco setup`, which will rebuild things that might need to be rebuilt after the upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a comment, but I needed some formatting...

The error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/minimal-racket/6.10/lib/racket/Racket.framework/Versions/6.11_3m/Racket
```

means that you are missing a binary. That explains why running `raco` didn't fix anything - since `raco` handles Racket byte compiled files.

Like Alexis I recommend using one of the official installers from:

```
http://download.racket-lang.org/
```

Less trouble in the long run.